# PHP Get name of a specific html element via get_file_contents

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I retrieve html of an external page with get_file_contents

In this html code i only need to get the "name" of the 4 firts `<a>` elements that actualy have a "name".

`<a>` element look like this :

```
<a name="1991562"></a>
```

And i want to display name of 4 firts `<a>` element like this:
1991562,1991563,1991564,1991565

Is there a way to do that easily with php ?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementsbytagname.php

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->loadHTML('<html><body>Test<br><a name="112">test</a>  <a>test 2</a></body></html>');

$a = $doc->getElementsByTagName('a');
foreach ($a as $link) {
   $name = $link->getAttribute('name');
   if($name && is_numeric($name)){
    echo $name;
   }
}

?>
```